# I need help in figuring out the error in the following snippet to sort a stack

Tags: c, sorting

I have read the answers in sorting of stack in the site but I'm unable to implement my code.

```
void sort(int *stack) {
    if(!isempty()) {
        int y=pop(stack,&i1);

        int max=y;
        int j;
        while(!isempty) {
                int x=pop(stack,&i1);
                if(x>y) {
                    max=x;
                    push(y,stack1,&i2);
                } else
                    push(x,stack1,&i2);
            }
        push(max,stack2,&i3);
    }
    int *temp;
    temp=stack1;
    stack1=stack;
    stack=temp;
    sort(stack);
}
```

I m using `&` operator for `stack` pointer since I m using three stacks.Can someone please explain why is it becoming an infinite loop? `stack` is the original array , `stack 1` is the temporary one and `stack 3` has the final sorted values.

Comment: What `!isempty()`? And why does it appear once as a function-call and once as a symbol of some sort??? Please spend some time clearing up your code (at least to the point where it compiles successfully).

Comment: You have `isempty()` (a function) and `isempty` (a variable). This seems confusing.

Comment: You never return. It's an infinite loop because your tail-end recursion has no stopping point.

Answer (score 0):

You have To check the "x > max" instead of "x > y" In the first place.

There are many confusing things. As mentioned in a comment, There is a variable and a function named "isempty". I suppose it was a typing error, Where it must be the function "isempty".

Your function "sort" can't get out of it as you call it at the very bottom of the function. It always Loops back to itself. (infinite recursive function). So the command "sort(stack)" must be inside the while loop. (with all the helping commands to it).

I can't go further as this problem is more confusing. Just try to make these errors and make your code compile first !